# Trouble displaying toolbar from activity using fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Hello i'm having trouble displaying my toolbar using fragment. I am integrating my app with facebook. I am able to connect to facebook and get basic user profile details such as first name, last name and user profile pic. Now i passed the information from my main activity to my second activity. My second activity will be using fragments. Now i made a fragment that holds toolbar, the user name and pic. But i am having trouble displaying the fragment. Will someone tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thank you. below are my files.

color.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="toolBar">#00ff80</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#cc3300</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#C51162</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="windowBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="navigationBarColor">#808080</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF80AB</color>
    <color name="backgroundColor">#003399</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <!--  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> -->
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
  <!--  </style> -->
    <!-- Base Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>

</resources>
```

activity_second.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
         >
      <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <fragment
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:layout="@layout/first_fragment"
              android:name="edu.sjsu.cmpe277.termproject.Fragments.FirstFragment"
              android:id="@+id/toolBar_fragment"
              />

      </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

first_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/users_FirstName"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:hint="JJJJ"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
    </com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView>

</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:gravity="top|start">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

FirstFragment.java:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunicator {

    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView textView;
    private FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
//    private GetDetails getdetails;
    //private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_fragment, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        textView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try{
            fragmentCommunicator =(FragmentCommunicator)context;
        }
        catch(ClassCastException ex) {
            throw new ClassCastException(ex.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

    }

    @Override
    public void setDetails(String userId, String name) {

    }
```

secondActivity.java:

```
    public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentCommunicator{

private FirstFragment firstFragment;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private Intent intent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    intent = getIntent();
    String firstName = intent.getStringExtra("firstName");
    String userId = intent.getStringExtra("Id");

    firstFragment = (FirstFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.toolBar_fragment);
   intent = getIntent();
    String firstName = intent.getStringExtra("firstName");
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("lastName");
    String userId = intent.getStringExtra("Id");

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void setDetails(String userId, String name) {

    FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.toolBar_fragment);
            if(firstFragment !=null) {
                firstFragment.setDetails(userId, name);
            }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's couple of nice points for you:

- Don't put  inside fragments layout, it would be much better and smarter to handle toolbar from activity. (You can still use options menu in your fragment to add components to your toolbar.
- in your second activity xml prevents from using , put your  layout in the top of this xml, and  container to do fragment transaction on it.

Your fragment should handle only what they made for, your second activity should replace your fragment (into the container) and handle the toolbar.

Good luck

Comment: i believe on point 2 you mentioned. i did that with my activity_second.xml